# Why can't I assign an array to pointer directly in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following program. However, I can't understand why I have to pass the address of the array. When they are both pointing to the same address. Which is the address of the first element of the array of int's.

I get a warning when I try and do this "assignment from incompatible pointer type":

```
ptr = var;
```

Complete source code:

```
void print_values(int (*ptr)[5])
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d: [ %d ]\n", i, (*ptr)[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* declare a pointer to an array integers */
    int (*ptr)[5] = NULL;
    /* array of integers */
    int var[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    /* assign the address of where the array is pointing to (first element) */
    ptr = &var;
    /* Both are pointing to the exact same address */
    printf("var  [ %p ]\n",(void*)var);
    printf("&var [ %p ]\n", (void*)&var);

    print_values(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code with `gcc 4.4.4 c89 -Wall -Wextra -O0`

Comment: I tried to reword your title, since it was meaningless.  Please, verify if I picked the gist of your problem correctly.

Comment: I think your title sounds better than mine. Thanks.

Comment: You code snippet compiles fine. Do you mean you would get an error if you added `ptr = var` to main?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's purely a type issue.

In most expression contexts the name of an array (such as `var`) decays to a pointer to the initial element of the array, not a pointer to the array. [Note that this doesn't imply that `var` is a pointer - it very much is *not* a pointer - it just *behaves* like a pointer to the first element of the array in most expressions.]

This means that in an expression `var` normally decays to a pointer to an `int`, not a pointer to an array of `int`.

As the operand of the address-of operator (`&`) is one context where this decay rule doesn't apply (the other one being as operand of the `sizeof` operator). In this case the type of `&var` is derived directly from the type of `var` so the type is pointer to array of 5 `int`.

Yes, the pointers have the same address value (the address of an arrays first element is the address of the array itself), but they have different types (`int*` vs `int(*)[5]`) so aren't compatible in the assignment.

ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.3.2.1/4:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression of type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. ...

Comment: I thought that arrays only decay into pointers when called in a function. so in the expression. int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; int *ptr = arr; The arry would decay into a pointer when assigned to a pointer?

Comment: @robUK: It's not just function calls, it's most expression contexts where the decay occurs. The array decays when used to initialize a pointer; a pointer value is needed to initialize an a pointer to `int`, not an array of `int`.

Answer (score 6):

`var` itself is a `(*int)` pointing to the first element in your array. Pointers and arrays in C extremely similar. Change `int (*ptr)[5] = NULL;` to `int* ptr = NULL;` and `ptr = &var;` to `ptr = var;`

Answer (score 4):

C is a strongly typed language. When a function expects a parameter of type `int *`, you have to pass an argument of type `int *`. Not `double *`, not `char *`, but `int *`. Even if the actual numerical address in those `double *` or `char *` is "the same" as the one you want to pass, it still doesn't change anything - you still have to pass an `int *`. The language prohibits you from passing the value of wrong type.

This is exactly what happens in your case. The function takes a parameter of type `int (*)[5]`. That means that you have to pass the argument of that type. Passing an `int *` instead is not allowed. Whether the address is the same makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are assigning an array pointer (`var`) to a pointer that points to an array pointer (`(*ptr)[5]`), so that's why you get that warning.

Instead, try using

```
int *ptr = NULL;
```