# Assigning array name to pointer to array of characters

Tags: c

Why do I get a warning when I do this:

```
char (*arr_ptr)[];
char str[] = "string";

arr_ptr = str;
```

The warning is:

```
assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

But when I change the assignment to:

```
arr_ptr = &str;
```

The warning disappears. I thought `str`, `&str`, and `&str[0]` were all the same. So how would `str` or `&str[0]` be incompatible?

I think my code is being compiled by GCC since I'm running it on TextMate.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array) can probably help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I assign an array to pointer directly in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504506/why-cant-i-assign-an-array-to-pointer-directly-in-c)

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought `str`, `&str` and `&str[0]` were all the same.

No. `str` is `&str[0]` - both denote a pointer to the first array element.

`&str` points to the same place, but is a pointer to the complete array.

The diffrence is the type if you dereference the pointer.

Try

```
printf("%d %d %d",
       (int)sizeof(*str),
       (int)sizeof(*(&str)),
       (int)sizeof(*(&str[0])));
```

.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for editing. I wasn't aware that `sizeof` yields a `size_t`. Wouldn't it be better to use `%z`, or is that less portable?

Comment: `%z` doesn't even exist.  `%zu` is the correct format for `size_t`, but it's new in C99, and some C implementations probably don't support it; Microsoft in particular has been less than enthusiastic about supporting C99.  Converting to `int` and using `%d` is portable as long as the size doesn't exceed `INT_MAX` (which is at least 32767).  You can also cast to `unsigned long` and use `%lu` as long as the size doesn't exceed ULONG_MAX (which is at least 2147483647).

Answer (score 2):

In C, `str`, `&str` and `&str[0]` refer to the same address - an array's label is simply a way of referring to the address of the start of a contiguous block of memory. `str` and `&str` are obviously of different types, however, `&str` being of type `char (*)[]`.

If you want `arr_ptr` to *point* to `"string"`, you merely have to do:

`char *arr_ptr = str;`

`arr_ptr` is simply of type `char*`, a single level pointer to `char`.

**EDIT:** In case I accidentally avoided the question, the reason why assigning `&str` to `char (*arr_ptr)[]` removes the error is because of the fact that `&str` is of type `char (*)[]`, and `str` is only of type `char[]` (which can decay to `char*`).

Comment: Yes, I know. But I still don't see why `str` or `&str[0]` is incompatible. You just changed the definition of `arr_ptr` which avoided the question.

Comment: @NSCoder because str is an array of chars, whereas arr_ptr is an array of pointers to chars.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. `arr_ptr` is a pointer to array of chars. Wouldn't an array of pointers to char would simply be `*foo[]`?

Comment: Sorry, but **No**: `str != &str`.  In the context, `str` is an array of characters, and `&str` is a pointer to an array of characters, and even if the numerical value of the address is the same, the types are different so the equality doesn't apply.

Comment: @NSCoder - beg your pardon, you are right, getting mixed up between operator and declaration precedence

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I was talking about the addresses, assume they were cast as void*s. I didn't mean `str == &str == &str[0]` to be an actual C statement. Anyway I'll reword it because it does look shonky.

Comment: @NSCoder: If my answer wasn't clear, the reason the warning goes away is because `&str` is of type `char (*)[]`, the same type as `arr_ptr`. I edited the answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you were trying was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *arr_ptr;
    char str[] = "string";

    arr_ptr = str;

    printf("%s \n", arr_ptr);
    printf("%s \n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

The following program adds one more dimension for your understanding.

```
int main()
{
    char **arr_ptr;
    char *str[] = {"string1", "string2", "string3"};
    int i;

    arr_ptr = str;

    for (i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", arr_ptr[i]);
        printf("%s \n", str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The code written in the question - the compiling code - is fine.  It is just different (and less usual).  You need to know what it does, but it is valid and different from either of your suggestions.

Comment: I thought by mentioning the (possible) correct way, @NSCoder would be able to figure out his mistake in assigning the incompatible types. Apologies if my approach is not right!