# C- Iterating over an array of structs passed through a void*

Tags: c, arrays, struct, iteration, void-pointers

I have a function

```
struct Analysis reduce (int n, void* results)
```

Where n is the number of files to be analyzed, and I'm passing an array of Analysis structs to results.

The Analysis struct is defined as follows:

```
struct Analysis {
  int ascii[128]; //frequency of ascii characters in the file
  int lineLength; //longest line in the file
  int lineNum; //line number of longest line
  char* filename;
}
```

I've cast the void * as such,

```
struct Analysis resArray[n];
struct Analysis* ptr = results;
resArray[0] = ptr[0];
```

but I can't figure out how to iterate through the resArray properly. I've tried

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
  printf("lineLength: %d\n", resArray[i].lineLength);
}
```

with n = 3, and I'm getting garbage values. resArray[0] is correct, but resArray[1] is an insanely high number and resArray[2] is just 0. Why wouldn't resArray[1] or resArray[2] give the correct values? If I was incrementing the address incorrectly then it would make sense but I'm just accessing the array at a certain index. Pretty lost here!

Comment: try `ptr[i]` instead of `resArray[i]`.

Comment: Using `resArray[0] = ptr[0];` you are copying the first element of `results` into first element of `resArray`. Other values are left uninitilized.

Comment: `Why wouldn't resArray[1] or resArray[2] give the correct values` - because no assignment was performed to those elements? All you did with `resArray[0] = ptr[0];` was pull the first element. Everything else is *indeterminate* in that array. But.. why stuff them into another array in the first place. What's wrong with just using `ptr[i].linelength` ?

Comment: You've not assigned anything to `resArray[3]`; why would you expect anything other than garbage?

Comment: You should chat with [Patrick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6079824/patrick); he's also asking about accessing `struct Analysis` via `void *`.

Comment: Tell me something, why you have to use `resArray`? Why can't you use `ptr` directly?

Comment: Why do you use `void*` ?

Comment: I wanted to only use ptr, but I thought I had to make it an array. As in 'struct Analysis* ptr[n] = (struct Analysis*) results' but that didn't work. Thanks for the help! Sorry I'm still learning!

Comment: If you really need a copy, notice that deep-copy may be needed as your struct contains a pointer.

Comment: If you know what type is being passed, why are you passing a `void *`?    Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

resArray[0] is correct because there is "something":

```
resArray[0] = ptr[0];
```

Other elements are garbage because you didn't set there any values. If you want to copy entire array you need to change copying method to:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  resArray[i] = ptr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a pointer to an array directly because they are different types`since array[n] is type struct analysis(*)[n] and ptr is type struct analysis(*)`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504506/why-cant-i-assign-an-array-to-pointer-directly-in-c) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this code will help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define d 3
struct Analysis {
    int ascii[128];
    int lineLength;
    int lineNum;
    char *filename;
};

struct Analysis Analyses[d];

struct Analysis reduce(int n, void *results) {

    struct Analysis resArray[n];
    struct Analysis *ptr = results;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        resArray[i] = ptr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("lineLength: %d\n", ptr[i].lineLength);
    }

    return *ptr;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Analysis a = {{5}, 2, 2, "George"};
    struct Analysis b = {{6}, 3, 3, "Peter"};
    struct Analysis c = {{7}, 4, 4, "Jane"};
    Analyses[0] = a;
    Analyses[1] = b;
    Analyses[2] = c;
    reduce(d, &Analyses);
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it [online](http://ideone.com/jXwLEg).